# Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org". Error (69): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, mobile-application

Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org". Error (69): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)

that is the error in flutter when i create or upgrade flutter:

[image: that is the error in flutter when i create or upgrade flutter]

Comment: try running flutter clean and flutter pub cache repair

Comment: i try that command and i get those errors..

Comment: D:\MyApps\flutapp>flutter pub get
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 3 in 4 seconds...
Running "flutter pub get" in flutapp...                                \Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

Comment: D:\MyApps\flutapp>flutter clean
.packages does not exist.
Did you run "flutter pub get" in this directory?

D:\MyApps\flutapp>flutter pub get
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
Running "flutter pub get" in flutapp...                                \Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

Comment: D:\MyApps\flutapp>flutter pub cache repair
Resetting Git repository for assets_for_android_views 0.1.0...
Downloading _discoveryapis_commons 0.1.9...
Failed to repair _discoveryapis_commons 0.1.9. Error:
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
Downloading analyzer 0.38.5...
Failed to repair analyzer 0.38.5. Error:
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
Downloading analyzer_plugin 0.2.1...

Comment: I got this error when  .packages file deleted from the project. Once i created that file inside a project everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This would also mean that flutter might not be able to connect to your device if you're trying flutter run onto an Android device.

The solution for this would be to change the DNS address of your network to 8.8.8.8(Google's DNS) or any other address:

MacOSX:

1. Open "System Preferences"
2. Click on "Network"
3. Select the network which your computer is connected and click on "Advanced"
4. Select "DNS", Select the "+" button, type "8.8.8.8" (Google's DNS) or if you prefer OpenDNS, "208.67.222.222"
5. Select "Ok" and "Apply"

Windows & Linux:
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

After this reopen the terminal and try again.

Answer (score 1):

**What didn't work for me:-**

```
flutter clean

flutter pub cache repair
```

**And what WORKED!**

```
killall -9 dart //THIS STOPPED THE CONTINUE REQUEST
```

After **changing the Wifi/Internet Connection**, it worked strangely!

It seems some DNS cache issue (not 100% sure), but I am happy that it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I had run into this problem earlier today!
The thing I discovered was my wifi wasn't working properly and my laptop went to airplane mode. I would suggest to check the network connection is working or not at that very moment. And things are more easy to solve than it seems, so chill and keep finding answer with a cool head. Don't be like me and waste 2 hours of development time. Peace.

Answer (score 0):

very simple but your internet connection may be broken

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it will happen with me when my laptop was not connected to internet after connecting it my problem solve

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).