# Stuck at flutter doctor, anyone can help me?

Tags: flutter, helper, flutter-doctor

I'm a beginner
And don't know how to solve this problem:
When running flutter doctor, the result is always like this:
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org", pub get failed (server unavailable..attemting retry 1 in 1 second....

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Is path set for flutter SDK ? Does your user have admin rights to make changes to SDK directory ? Are you able to access URL `https://pub.dartlang.org` ?

Comment: Ya, the path on set, i dont know with your second question can you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Where do you do? if in the VSCode or Android Studio application, make sure the location is appropriate
   C: \ Users \ User \ AndroidStudioProjects \ ..>
2. Have you set the location for the flutter

Comment: In cmd, im set the location for the flutter in C: \Android\flutter

Comment: the case is the same, check here for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412592/could-not-resolve-url-https-pub-dartlang-org-error-69-unable-to-pub-upg